# How do you view all available child fields in GraphiQL?

Tags: graphql, graphiql

Let's say I have a field called featuredImage.

If I start typing "id," for example, it will show that as an available sub field using autocomplete.

But what if you don't know what the sub fields are?

```
{
  featuredImage {
    // What fields are available?
  }
}
```

How do you use GraphQL to show what sub fields are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the keyboard shortcut by doing 'ctrl + space' and it should bring up all the options, similar in many text editors.

```
{ 
  featuredImage {
    /* ctrl + space */
    /* displays options */
  }
}
```

Comment: Sweet! I didn't know about that one. Thanks!

Comment: No Problem! Check it out also in your text editor. Doing something like - 

const myarray = []

myarray. /* ctrl + space */ and you will get those auto complete options of map, filter, push etc. 

This has been super helpful for me in graphiql, and typed npm packages.